# smarty custom modifier with sprintf, passing multiple params into function

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

How would I extend the `$insert` so that I can pass multiple parameters into the function e.g
`{"Sample text %s this more %s."|inject:$foo:$foo2}`.

At the moment it only works with 1 param.

```
/**
 * Smarty inject modifier plugin
 *
 * Type:     modifier<br>
 * Name:     inject<br>
 * Purpose:  sprintf with a IF empty wrapper
 *
 */
function smarty_modifier_inject($string, $insert)
{
    if(!empty($insert))
        return sprintf($string, $insert);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to modify inject function to take arbitrary number of arguments, like this:

```
function inject(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    if(count($args) > 1){
        return call_user_func_array('sprintf', $args);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I add the check if the arguments are not empty?